# How using 'extended' option for Surf algorithm

Tags: opencv, sift, surf

I want to concatenate SIFT and SURF descriptors to see if it gives better accuracy so I need that SIFT and SURF have the same number of columns. So I want to code on 128 bits SURF descriptors and so I need to use "extended" option. I do this like it :

```
SurfFeatureDetector detector2(minHessian);
detector2.extended=1;
```

and then:

`extractor2.compute(img, keypoints_4, descriptors2);`

But I do this :

```
cout<<"descriptors2   "<<descriptors2.rows<<" +  "<<descriptors2.cols<<endl;
```

it gives that

> descriptors2   168 +  64

So my question is to take into account the extended parameter ? What am I doing wrong ? Should I need to give a similar parameter to the extractor?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want better accuracy, maybe look outside those old descriptor based methods. im not sure concatenating them would do much for you - surf is essentially doing a very similar thing under the hood as sift, just with more approximations to make it faster...

Comment: @chris Thanks for your advice but anyway, do you know how using Surf _extended_ parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple. I needed to add

```
extractor2.extended=1;
```